# How to wire ceiling fan with a down rod longer than the wiring?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I'm replacing a ceiling fan that has a 24" down rod. The old fan had 16 AWG motor leads 12 inches long. Additional 16 AWG was wire nutted to the motor leads and run through the down rod to the ceiling junction box. The new fan has 14" leads.

Is the down rod considered a conduit since it was added to a UL listed fan so splices are not allowed in it? Is the extension of 16 AWG OK? or should it be 14 AWG?  (I know, two questions but come on guys and gals)

Answer (score 2):

Your rod is going to tie to the metal plate screwed to your junction box. If you bond that plate like you should (they typically give you a handy green screw or wire just for that) then your metal pole is grounded and you're good.

As to the wire to the motor, I would put stranded 14 gauge THHN in because you can typically buy it by the foot. I typically see 16 gauge only in small spools (overkill for a maximum 5' pole)

Comment: I would buy a couple of spools (25') of THHN stranded, just 'cause it's handy to have around for other projects, too.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use the added #16 AWG wire. I replaced it with #14 AWG stranded since I had around 2000 ft of it and just spliced it in the down rod.
Interestingly though, I was at a retirement lunch for a few inspectors and asked them the above question. They wouldn't consider the down rod a conduit because it couldn't be completely assembled and then wire pulled from start to finish. They also wouldn't allow #16 AWG to be spliced in the down rod and extended into the junction box. Their reasoning was that #16 AWG can't be run into a junction box unless it's part of a UL listed device. If the fan came with 36" of #16, then it would be OK but adding it on to existing wire would not be OK. A rookie inspector mentioned he had approved an installation where a straight metal conduit body stamped with cu in size had been attached to a 10' down rod and then to the top of the fan with nipples and lock nuts. The fan wire was then spliced to the #14 in the conduit body. The retiring inspector said that should not have been approved because it wasn't a defined use of a conduit body and not UL listed for that weight or torquing of the fan.

Don't worry, I'm not accepting this as an answer.